# xCode autolayout not working for all iPhone screens

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm done my app, and the last thing I'm trying to finish up is the AutoLayout, I created the autolayout with reference to an iPhone 6 screen, and it fits perfectly on it and the 6+. But for the 5 and 4 it becomes bunched and isn't working well. I've tried everything from resizing, switching modes and etc. They should all look like the first screenshot.I've added screenshots.The order is: iPhone 6, iPhone 5, iPhone 4s

Here are the constraints:

On the big UIImage: 
Align Centre x to temperature Label
Align Centre y to White Indicator
Align top space to City Label
Align bottom space to temperature Label

On Temperature Label:

Width = 150
Height = 44
Align centre x to Image View Above
Align centre x to white indicator
Bottom space to loading label (right underneath it)
top space to imageview

All the time labels are aligned left and right to the temp labels as well as top and bottom space between weather images

First small weather image:
Leading to superview
bottom space to superview
align centre x to time label above it
trailing space to uiimage on the right
align bottom/top to other uiimages on the right

second small weather image: same as above except width = 80 and no leading space to superview
I've tried removing this one, but whenever i do the UIImage shrinks, and this is the only way I can keep it the same size as others

third small image: same as the first, but includes leading space to superview

fourth: same as the first and includes trailing space to superview

Turn Off Alarm button at the bot: 
Align centre x to temperature label (the big one)
Top space to smaller temp labels
Trailing to superview
Height = 100

[image: iPhone 6][image: iphone5][image: iphone4]

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information before anyone can help you.  What are your views and what constraints are applied to them?

Comment: What constraints are you using? Do you understand how constraints work?

Comment: Yeah I do, I added a list of my constraints above

Comment: Did you manually add all of those constraints or did you use "Add Missing Constraints" option?

Comment: Hey I ended up solving my problem, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else ever runs into this problem, my main issue was that I was using size classes despite the fact I was only creating an app for iPhones. So by clicking on the storyboard and clicking on any view controller and going to file inspector (first icon) I unchecked the size classes button. This way I could add autolayout and constraints and it would work across all iPhone screens. Although small adjustments were required to make it work it was much easier

Comment: The only problem I can see with size classes is that you accidentally added  some constraints in a certain size class that wasn't shared across all devices. Adding it from the "default" size class would make be available for all screen sizes.